# Fail a Future from a mapping method

Tags: scala, future

I have a `Future[Option[X]]` and would like to "unbox" the inner `Option` in a way that the outer `Future` fails if the `Option` is empty, and directly provides the value otherwise. In other words, I'd like to flatten the whole thing to a `Future[X]`.

The most obvious approach I can think of is using `map` and matching in there, but I don't see how to end up in a failing `Future`. Throwing an exception as follows seems to simply bubble that one up, crashing the application:

```
xOptionFuture map(optional => {
  optional match {
    case x: X => x
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }
})
```

Is there a way to trigger `Future` failure from within `map`? Or even a simpler/more idiomatic solution?

Comment: Throwing from inside map should do exactly what you are looking for. Not sure what you got "bubbling up", but it must be thrown from a different place ...  I am not sure what `this.get` does, and why you need so many braces, generally, just `xOptionFuture.map(_.get)` should do what you want.

Comment: Oh, the `this.get` part was a copy-paste error; removed it now. I'm new to Scala (coming mostly from Java) and not so used to it yet, hence the weird bracing. :)

Comment: @Dima You're right, it *did* do the right thing. My problem was I wasn't handling it properly in the consumer of the resulting future, causing the exception to surface in unexpected places. Also, nice tip with `.map(_.get)`, I think I'm starting to grasp it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `flatMap` instead such as:

```
xOptionFuture.flatMap {
    case Some(x) => Future.successful(x)
    case None => Future.failed(new IllegalArgumentException("Option is None"))
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary. Throwing from `.map` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, throwing from `map` will also have this result but I prefer this more explicit version because I think it better conveys the intention i.e. the fact that the author of the code does expect that `Option` might be empty. If the `Option` is not expected to be empty under any normal circumstances, I would prefer `.map(_.get)`

Comment: If the code expects that it might be empty, it shouldn't be throwing to begin with :) Exceptions signal unexpected condition by definition.

Comment: @Dima, Well throwing an exception is probably not a good FP-way altogether. But the way the question is worded made my believe that this is a kind of actually expected scenario with an explicit handling. Obviously I can easily be wrong.